# MySQL - Left Join + Group by not working as expected

Tags: mysql

So,

I have used LEFT JOIN time and time again, I have never experienced an issue with it until now, I can't for the life of me work it out! Please take a look.

**Here is a snippet of data from the table I am working with . -**

```
ITEM_NO  R_TYPE POS
394392      BT1 POS1
394392      BT1 POS1
394392      BT1 POS1
394392      BT1 POS1
394392      BT1 POS1
394392      BT2 POS2
394392      BT2 POS2
394392      BT2 POS2
394397      BT1 POS1
394397      BT1 POS1
394397      BT1 POS3
394397      BT1 POS3
394397      BT1 POS2
394397      BT2 POS2
394397      BT2 POS1
394397      BT2 POS1
394444      BT3 POS1
```

I am trying to run a left join query to Count the **distinct** **Item No's** that have certain **POS** criterias and finally grouping them by **R_TYPE**

```
Here is the SQL I have tried - 

SELECT * FROM 
          ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ITEM_NO) AS CNT1, R_TYPE, 
          FROM LIVE_ITEMS WHERE AND R_TYPE LIKE 'BT%' AND
          POS NOT IN ('POS8') ) J1
           LEFT JOIN
           ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ITEM_NO) AS CNT2, R_TYPE, 
          FROM LIVE_ITEMS WHERE AND R_TYPE LIKE 'BT%' AND
          POS  IN ('POS1','POS2','POS3') ) J2
          ON J1.R_TYPE= J2.R_TYPE
          GROUP BY J1.R_TYPE
```

**If i run this sql I get the following result -**

```
CNT1    R_TYPE  CNT2    R_TYPE
137     BT1     137     BT1
```

This is not exactly what I wanted, I was expecting the following and can't understand why..

**Expected Data -**

```
CNT1    R_TYPE  CNT2    R_TYPE
137     BT1     137     BT1
45      BT2     76      BT2
98      BT3     102     BT3
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected your query. Please check.

```
 SELECT * FROM 
      ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.ITEM_NO) AS CNT1, a.R_TYPE 
          FROM LIVE_ITEMS a
         WHERE a.R_TYPE LIKE 'BT%' 
           AND a.POS NOT IN ('POS8')
         GROUP BY a.R_TYPE ) J1
   LEFT JOIN
       ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.ITEM_NO) AS CNT2, b.R_TYPE 
           FROM LIVE_ITEMS b
          WHERE b.R_TYPE LIKE 'BT%' 
            AND b.POS  IN ('POS1','POS2','POS3')
         GROUP BY b.R_TYPE) J2
   ON J1.R_TYPE= J2.R_TYPE
 GROUP BY J1.R_TYPE
```

Comment: Edited it.. that and was mean't to be a join.. I'd just stripped out alot of the sql columns to make it digestible.

Comment: This produces an error... #1052 - Column 'R_TYPE' in field list is ambiguous, I have tried adding J1.R_TYPE and J2.R_TYPE also, and still get an error..

Comment: I have modified my query. try it out now

Comment: Sweet as. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Without GROUP BY, there is a single group and it is indeterminate which  value to choose for the group

```
  SELECT * FROM 
  ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LIVE_ITEMS.ITEM_NO) AS CNT1, LIVE_ITEMS.R_TYPE, 
  FROM LIVE_ITEMS WHERE LIVE_ITEMS.R_TYPE LIKE 'BT%' AND
  LIVE_ITEMS.POS NOT IN ('POS8') GROUP BY LIVE_ITEMS.R_TYPE) J1
   LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LIVE_ITEMS.ITEM_NO) AS CNT2, LIVE_ITEMS.R_TYPE, 
  FROM LIVE_ITEMS WHERE LIVE_ITEMS.R_TYPE LIKE 'BT%' AND
  LIVE_ITEMS.POS  IN ('POS1','POS2','POS3') GROUP BY LIVE_ITEMS.R_TYPE) J2
  AND J1.R_TYPE= J2.R_TYPE
  GROUP BY J1.R_TYPE
```

without Group by `COUNT(DISTINCT ITEM_NO)` always give one result

Comment: This produces an error... #1052 - Column 'R_TYPE' in field list is ambiguous, I have tried adding J1.R_TYPE and J2.R_TYPE also, and still get an error..

Comment: LIVE_ITEMS.R_TYPE try this please @Dan

Comment: That produces this error. . "#1052 - Column 'R_TYPE' in field list is ambiguous" again

Comment: SELECT * FROM 
          ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LIVE_ITEMS.ITEM_NO) AS CNT1, LIVE_ITEMS.R_TYPE, 
          FROM LIVE_ITEMS WHERE LIVE_ITEMS.R_TYPE LIKE 'BT%' AND
          LIVE_ITEMS.POS NOT IN ('POS8') GROUP BY LIVE_ITEMS.R_TYPE) J1
           LEFT JOIN
          ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LIVE_ITEMS.ITEM_NO) AS CNT2, LIVE_ITEMS.R_TYPE, 
          FROM LIVE_ITEMS WHERE LIVE_ITEMS.R_TYPE LIKE 'BT%' AND
          LIVE_ITEMS.POS  IN ('POS1','POS2','POS3') GROUP BY LIVE_ITEMS.R_TYPE) J2
          AND J1.R_TYPE= J2.R_TYPE
          GROUP BY J1.R_TYPE

Comment: please try this query @Dan